# Scrolling menu visible/hide

Tags: html, menu, scroll, parallax

I need help to design a header menu like the website: http://www.whiteboard.is, but I have no idea the technology used and any build in script to use here.
The main idea is when a user scroll the page after a certain section the top menu will be visible.
I would be glad if you guide me to done the task asap.
Best regards

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial may be useful:
http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/create-stay-on-top-menu-css3-jquery/